# find a 5-digits $q$ such that $2^q+17$ be a prime

Tags: prime-numbers

How we can find a 5-digits number $q$ such that $2^q+17$ be a prime number? Does there exist such number?

Comment: from where does this problem come?

Comment: I do not know. Someone asked me :)

Comment: Honestly, you find it by testing every $5$-digit number until you find one that gives a prime.  You can sieve out some based on divisibility by small primes (e.g. if $q$ is even then $2^q+17$ is a multiple of $3$), but you'll still probably have to check many hundreds of cases by computer.  Why don't you ask "someone" to find a $5$-digit $q$ such that $2^q + 78557$ is prime? :)

Comment: The only such number is 77121. Thank Neal Sloane, Robert Wilson and Robert Price for the answer. http://oeis.org/A057200